# MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly ==> System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, memory-error

Sometimes, rebuilding my solution I get following error. Solution is huge, 270+ projects and I have no idea how to get rid of this error. It happens sometimes, most of the times solution builds correctly. I have 32GB RAM, so it is not a problem, I have also a ReSharper, a friend at work don't have it, and have never experienced the error, so maybe there is a problem. Anyway, if anybody have idea how to repair it, I would be very glad to hear it ;)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(559,5): Error:  MSB4018: The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
31>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: (x86) looks like you are using a 32bit process which would result in a limit of 4GB of memory for the process (and the process requesting more than that). Double check using task manager that the process is running in 64bit mode.

Comment: @Gizmo - Visual Studio being a 32-bit process is not the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a known problem reported in
[Unbounded SQLite instances/connections contributing to OOM failures #22650](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22650).

The problem was apparently solved in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5,
and the fix may have been back-ported to 15.4.

Updating Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version should solve the problem
(if it is indeed the same).

---

Since that didn't solve the problem, it's worthwhile noting that the
OutOfMemoryException error does not mean lack of memory, but rather
the impossibility of *allocating* memory.
I will explain below why these are not the same.

As Visual Studio is a 32-bit program, its memory space is limited to 4 GB.
From this, it can "only" use about 2 GB for its data, the rest used by
Windows software and for programs.
Physical memory is allocated virtual addresses in this space, so that
some addresses are already allocated and some are not.
There is no garbage collection mechanism possible, so that an address,
once allocated, stays allocated.

Imagine, for example that from the 2 GB that are available, 100 MB
are allocated, and one wants to allocate an additional 1 GB.
Logically, the available memory is far more than enough.
However, if the 100 MB are allocated in the middle of the 2 GB space,
it is no longer possible to allocate 1 GB of *contiguous* memory.
In this case, the OutOfMemoryException condition will be raised,
although it looks flatly impossible.

This case can arise when memory is allocated and freed in such a way
that allocated memory fragments are scattered through the available
address space and only leave "holes" that are not enough for a large
allocation.

Therefore, there are only two possibilities:

1. A bug in Visual Studio, as for example when attempting to increase
   the length of an instance of the `StringBuilder` class beyond what is
   specified by its current `MaxCapacity` property, will also cause the
   OutOfMemoryException condition.
2. Too many allocations are done, so that, even freed, the memory is
   too fragmented.

Your case seems to better fit the second case, but your options for a
solution here are pretty limited.

A 64-bit version of Visual Studio would solve the problem by enlarging
the address space, but that is not in the
[Visual Studio Roadmap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs-roadmap).

Your other option is to reduce memory allocation as much as possible.
You could reduce the number of add-ons of Visual Studio or try to
break this enormous VS solution into smaller ones.
Or you could close and restart Visual Studio, since some memory allocations
are done in parallel by Visual Studio threads, so there is a random
element involved.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have newest version. I downloaded all new VS about month ago, and even after update that didn't help. Some coworkes have same problem as well.

Comment: I have added to my answer.